# How to implement Bayesian optimization with Keras tuneR

Tags: r, keras

I am hoping to run Bayesian optimization for my neural network via keras tuner.

I have the following code so far:

```
build_model <- function(hp) {                                
  model <- keras_model_sequential()
  
  model %>%  layer_dense(units = hp$Int('units', min_value = 10,  max_value = 50, step = 10), 
                         activation = "relu",  
                         input_shape = dim(X_pca_scores_scaled)[[2]]) %>%
    layer_dropout(rate = hp$Float('rate', min_value = 0,  max_value = 0.5, step = 0.1)) %>%
    layer_dense(units = hp$Int('units', min_value = 0,  max_value = 50, step = 10), 
                activation = "relu") %>%
    layer_dropout(rate = hp$Float('rate', min_value = 0,  max_value = 0.5, step = 0.1)) %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1) %>%
    compile(
      optimizer = "adam",
      loss = "mse",
      metrics = c("mae"))
  return(model)
}

tuner <- kerastuneR::BayesianOptimization(
  objective = 'mae',
  max_trials = 30)

stop_early <- callback_early_stopping(monitor = "mae",
                                      patience = 5,
                                      min_delta = 0.25,
                                      mode = "min")

tuner %>% fit_tuner(np_array(X_pca_scores_scaled),
                    np_array(train_targets),
                    epochs = 30, 
                    callbacks = c(stop_early))
```

The above code will lead to the following error:

```
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: 'BayesianOptimizationOracle' object has no attribute 'search'
```

I'm not sure what an oracle is...so I know the problem is somewhere in my implementation regarding that.

Comment: This issue has been raised with the authors of the R package. (https://github.com/EagerAI/kerastuneR/issues/44)

Comment: U might want to look here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kerastuneR/vignettes/BayesianOptimisation.html. Trying to figure it out myself rn